# AccountManager which account was removed

Tags: android, account, accountmanager

I know that the [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)'s  [`addOnAccountsUpdatedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#addOnAccountsUpdatedListener%28android.accounts.OnAccountsUpdateListener,%20android.os.Handler,%20boolean%29) can be used to get notified about the changes of the list of accounts. If that kind of event happens, the framework will call the supplied [`OnAccountsUpdateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/OnAccountsUpdateListener.html)'s [`onAccountsUpdated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/OnAccountsUpdateListener.html#onAccountsUpdated%28android.accounts.Account%5b%5d%29) method. But the argument of the method only contains the list of accounts. How can i know which account was removed by the user? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you’re trying to do, you might get away with this:

```
private Set<Account> mAccountCache; // init & populated when the listener is registered

@Override
public void onAccountsUpdated(Account[] accounts) {
    // This code assumes we're only interested in removed items.
    final Set<Account> currentAccounts = new HashSet<Account>(Arrays.asList(accounts));
    final Set<Account> removedAccounts = new HashSet<Account>(mAccountCache);
    removedAccounts.removeAll(currentAccounts); // populated with Accounts that were removed.
}
```

Comment: I thought about this solution, but i hoped there is another way. Thanks!